# Python Pandas replace values if not in value range

Tags: python, pandas, replace, range

I would like to replace all cells of a column if each value IS NOT in a specific value range.

E.g. value range between 0 and 10

The function should put np.NaN on all cells which are below 0 or above 10.

I tried with this:

```
df.loc[(df["B"] < 5 ), "B"] = np.NaN
```

but it only works with a specific value, not with a value range.

Is there a simple solution to replace all values outside a specific value range, without iterating through all rows?

Comment: df.B.between(0, 10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will choose between func

```py
df.loc[~df.B.between(0, 10), "B"] = np.nan
```

Comment: you want to add `~` in front of your condition to negate it then ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use np.where, specifying the desired conditions. If True, yield x, otherwise yield y.

```
np.where(condition, x, y)
```

So, the solution would be:

```
df.B = np.where((df.B < 0) & (df.B > 10), np.NaN, df.B)
```

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Will output something like that:

```sh
    A   B   C   D
0   2   5   6   2
1   0   4   0   0
2   4   3   9   0
3   5   1   1   8
4   2   3   6   5
5   3   0   3   9
6   0   4   3   4
7   4   1   4   5
8   0   5   1   5
9   6   7   4   4
```

Then if you apply the where condition:

```py
df.B = np.where((df.B < 6) & (df.B > 2), np.NaN, df.B)
```

```sh
    A   B   C   D
0   2   NaN 6   2
1   0   NaN 0   0
2   4   NaN 9   0
3   5   1.0 1   8
4   2   NaN 6   5
5   3   0.0 3   9
6   0   NaN 3   4
7   4   1.0 4   5
8   0   NaN 1   5
9   6   7.0 4   4
```

You can find more information here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Answer (score 2):

More closely to your original syntax

```
df.loc[(df["B"] < 0 )|(df["B"] > 10 ), "B"] = np.NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you can just do something like this:

```py
df["B"] = df["B"].where((df["B"] >= 0) & (df["B"] <= 10))

# or
df["B"] = df["B"].map(lambda x: x if 0 <= x <= 10 else None)

# or
df.loc[(df["B"] < 0) | (df["B"] > 10), "B"] = None
```