# Setting numbers outside of range as null

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with pandas df and I am trying to make all the numbers that are outside of range set as null, but having trouble

```
df['Numbers'] = df['Numbers'].mask((df['Numbers']< -10) & (df['Numbers']> 10), inplace=True)
```

So I want to keep the numbers between -10 and 10, if the numbers are outside of those two numbers, it should be set as null.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64465172/15497888) matches your approach most closely and mirrors [richardec's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70933316/15497888). Though you can also use Series between: `df.loc[~df['Numbers'].between(-10, 10), 'Numbers'] = np.nan` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64465224/15497888)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that immediately strikes out at me is that you're using `&` with your two conditions, so you're basically trying to select all numbers that are **both** less than `-10` **and** greater than `10`...which isn't gonna work ;)

I'd rewrite your code like this:

```
df.loc[df['Numbers'].lt(-10) | df['Numbers'].gt(10), 'Numbers'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Why use `.lt()` instead of `<`?

Comment: @Barmar I personally prefer using `.eq`, `.ne`, `.lt`, `.gt` etc., instead of their corresponding Python operators, because you don't have to wrap the conditions using them in parentheses when you're joining them with `&` or `|`. I.e., you can say `df[a.eq(b) | x.eq(y)]` instead of `df[(a == b) | (x == y)]`. Now, in that little example, the latter _does_ look more readable, but the former I prefer in larger settings where there are more complex and more complex conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
df['Numbers'] = df['Numbers'].where((df['Numbers']>-10) & (df['Numbers']<10))
```